# Update a Table with Dynamic SQL results within Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update, dynamic-sql

I have a table `EPFReport` where I need to fill the tables with a stored procedure.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[getEPFData] @EPFCol varchar(max) , @empID varchar(max)
AS 
   DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) ; 
   DECLARE @sql2 nvarchar(max); 

   set @sql = 'SELECT c.employeeID,c.empName, c.month,@sql1 from Common c where c.employeeID='+@empID 

   set @sql2= 'SELECT ' + @EPFCol + ' FROM Common where employeeID='+@empID       

   truncate table EPFReport; 

   INSERT into EPFReport (empID, empName, monthVal) 
      execute(@sql);
```

Up to here the requirement is fulfilled where the results of the query `@sql` will be inserted to the table. Now I need to update it with `@sql2` query, so the question is how to execute a query within a stored procedure for an `update` statement?

PS: for insert I've used

```
INSERT into EPFReport (empID, empName, monthVal) 
   execute(@sql);
```

Also here a set of results are returned (for each month). Not one row or cell of result. So assigning to a variable and updating doesn't work.

Update: the table contains these columns

```
[empID]  [empName]  [EPFItemValues]  [monthVal]
```

First query updates only 3 columns , and the second query should update the column `EPFItemValues`.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you trying to update what you have inserted?

Comment: Yes. But  column EPFItemValues is not filled with query @sql. SO at he begining it has NULL values. I'm trying to update that column with the qury "@sql2".

Answer (score 0):

Try;

Based on your comment, the following should work;

```
DECLARE @ID int = (Select MAX(ID) From EPFReport) // or SCOPE_IDENTITY

Update EPFReport
set EPFItemValues = @sql2
where ID = @ID
```

Comment: seems like , it doesnt execute the query. It updates the string value of the query eg: Query is @sql2= 'SELECT ' + @EPFCol + ' FROM Common where employeeID='+@empID .
But the values inserted will be "SELECT A002 FROM Common where employeeID=1001". Expected result is some int values assigned to the cells. But it assigns the query it self to the cell.

Comment: That is exactly what I was asking; Are you trying to update the column EPFItemValues to the SQL "SELECT A002 FROM Common where employeeID=1001"? If that is the case, the above will work as soon as you construct it properly.